# When to stop the whirlpool pump in an immersion whirlpool chiller?

Tags: chilling, wort-chiller, trub

What is the best temperature to stop the pump in an immersion whirlpool chiller ? And what about the time to wait the trub settling vs wort temperature ?

Consider both Ale and Lager.

Answer (score 4):

I stop chilling my ales when the surface temp/outlet pipe is about 21 degrees C.

It takes me about 40 minutes to chill 50 litres from boiling 100C down to 21C, so I guess in total I give the beer about an hour to settle after the boil is finished before draining into the ferm bins.

Cheers!

Comment: What about the settlement for very 'hoppy' beers ? Is enough to wait 1 hour to settle ? I've waiting about 30 minutes without good results.

Answer (score 0):

I stop running the pump and knock out the wort when it's 60F for ales and 48-50F for lagers.  By that point the trub has settled so I pump to a fermenter immediately.  Takes about 10-15 min, for ales and 15-20 min. for lagers.

Comment: You get that times to what batch size, @Denny Conn?

Comment: 5.5 gal. into the fermenter